# How can I find the maximum integer representable by a given count of cubes with single digit integers painted on the six sides

Tags: set, cartesian-product

Backstory - I have a baby on the way and have come across a product that is wooden cubes with single digits painted on the side.

They come in a set of three cubes and a units block, with the idea being that you can photograph your baby with them and arrange it such that it might say 20 days old, with a [2][0][days] block faces showing for example.

This got me wondering what approach I might take to understand how they might have decided which numbers to paint on which cubes, and if there is a way to calculate a maximum natural number that could be represented by N cubes.

I started to try to find an approach and quickly found that I was getting into complexity with trying to get a cartesian product of all cube combinations and felt like I was really missing an obvious answer that I'm overlooking

Answer (score 0):

You suggested that `N = 2` cubes could be arranged to display `[2][0]`,
denoting `2` × 10^1 + `0` × 10^0, or twenty.

Acquire a collection of numbered cubes, and
rotate each one so its maximum value is face up.
For standard Vegas dice that value would be `6`.
Presumably the novelty product of interest here will
have a bunch of cubes bearing the value `9`,
especially if you obtain more than one set of three.

Sort the cubes in descending numeric order,
and choose the first `N` of them.
(For example, given `N = 4` you might obtain `9999`.)